# Export multiple print statements to csv using python 3.5

Tags: python-3.5, export-to-csv

I have csv file which have two columns and i want to export it into the format i want. SO far i am able to print it into shell, i am struck with exporting that into csv file. Below is the code so far I have tried.

```
import csv
with open('file.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    next(csv_reader)
    sku = 0
    with open('newfile.csv','w') as new_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

        for i in csv_reader:
            sku = sku + 1
            csv_writer.writerow(i)
            print("message:: {")
            print("  Message ID    :",sku)
            print("  sku           :", i)
```

Any help or pointer would be helpfull. Thank you

Comment: I have figured it out.